# Lucene.Net using Ninject InSingletonScope()

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject, lucene.net

Reading up on Lucene, it seems it's recommeneded to use the same instance of IndexSearcher across all requests.

If I have a search class which is injected using ninject

```
public interface IPatientSearch
{
    void DoSearch(ref SearchDTO _search);

    //...
}
```

Would there be any issues binding it using InSingletonScope, which would ensure the same instance is shared across all requests?

```
        Bind<IPatientSearch>().To<PatientSearch>().InSingletonScope();
```

Am I missing any obvious pitfalls of using such an approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not an issue here from the Lucene.NET point of view; assuming your implementation of `IPatientSearch` creates an `IndexWriter` and uses that, there shouldn't be any problem.  The `IndexWriter` class is thread-safe, and you won't have any troubles accessing your Lucene.NET index.

However, you have to make sure that *all other aspects* of the `IPatientSearch` implementation are thread-safe; if this singleton is accessed from multiple threads, then any other state that you have in the implementation has to be thread-safe.  If your class is just a pass-through for calls to Lucene.NET, then you'll be fine, but if you have other state, then you need to make sure access to that state is synchronized.

You might want to create a thin abstraction around Lucene.NET and make *that* a singleton for the purposes of dependency injection, and have your other classes be instantiated normally (unless you need only *one* instance of that class).

Comment: Thanks CasperOne. I ensured the implementation was threadsafe. I've been using it for a couple of weeks now and no issues have shown up so far!